# Error in executing opencv in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, opencv

I just installed opencv 3.1 from this [link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide-on-Ubuntu-16.04). There was no issue or error in building up opencv. So, I checked my version using `cv2.__version__` , it is working fine but when I tested it using

```
temp = cv2.imread('test.png') 
cv2.imshow('img',temp)
```

I got this error, I don't understand where is the problem? There was no issue while building up and I followed the instructions carefully. Here is the error:

```
>>> cv2.imshow('img',temp)
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 583
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check that if you have installed `libgtk2.0` with the following command:

`sudo aptitude search libgtk2.0-dev`

If dependencies was broken, just install a fresh copy of it using below command:

`sudo aptitude install libgtk2.0-dev`

Comment: I ran the first line I got `sudo: aptitude: command not found`

Comment: I installed aptitude and the ran the command I got  `i   libgtk2.0-dev                   - development files for the GTK+ library` and    
`p   libgtk2.0-dev:i386              - development files for the GTK+ library`

Comment: I ran the next command as well and it says `libgtk2.0-dev is already installed at the requested version (2.24.30-1ubuntu1)` but it repeats the line two times, which is weird. So, it does not install it.

Comment: So, it seems that you have had libgtk2.0-dev. Thus build your files once again. Remember to put `WITH_GTK=ON` during cmake.

Answer (score 1):

you might need to disable QT and enable GTK_2_X

```
cmake -DWITH_IPP=ON -DWITH_QT=OFF -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_XINE=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF WITH_GTK_2_X=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
```

plus

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry buddy,I suffered the same and this is how I got rid of this error, see if you have installed opencv via pip or pip3 or apt-get, first you gotta uninstall it

```
sudo pip3 uninstall (what you wrote while installing)

or sudo pip uninstall (what you wrote while installing)

or sudo apt-get remove (what you wrote while installing)
```

and afterwards **build the opencv package from source code from github.**

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

cd ~/opencv

mkdir release

cd release

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..

make

sudo make install
```

This will solve the problem. All the best.